# Where can I edit the background color of php_codesniffer errors?

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

Working with PhpStorm 2021, I use squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.7
and want to change back phpcs warning background color.

phpcs has level ="warning"—I suppose that is some common option for all warnings, but where can I edit background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#customize-color-scheme

- `Settings/Preferences on macOS | Editor | Color Scheme | General`
- `Errors and Warnings | Warning` (or whatever error level you want to change)

[image]

---

You may also check out the PHP_Codesniffer inspection settings -- you should be able to change what actual style to use there etc.: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Quality tools | PHP_CodeSniffer validation`

[image]

***P.S.** All screenshots are made in the latest stable **PhpStorm 2022.2.3***