How to change background color of error declaration?
In PhpStorm 2024.1 when having error declaration in PHP code is colored in red yellow color, as below :

Where in settings can I change background color of this block, as it very similar of white current line - I would like some yellow background color?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74086737/783119 -- see the first part.
